# Is it safe to use startAfter/startAt with orderBy Firestore's Timestamp when its granularity is in microseconds?

Tags: timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

It seems the granularity of Timestamp is in microseconds, not in nanoseconds, as I get the following output when I log a Timestamp that is generated by Firestore server:

```
Timestamp { _seconds: 1543528094, _nanoseconds: 446000000 }
```

The last 6 digits of `_nanoseconds` is always 0.

So, when I do `orderBy('createdAt').startAfter(lastDocSnapshot)`, will it skip over all documents that have the exact same `createdAt` Timestamp value and start at the next timestamp value? Or will it start right after the last document snapshot as the name suggests even if there are other documents with the same Timestamp value?

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement is incorrect.  Timestamp granularity is in nanoseconds, not microseconds.  A timestamp stores an offset from unix epoch in seconds, then adds a fraction number of seconds (expressed as nanos) in addition to that.  Check the Android API docs for [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) for more detail.

Internally, Firestore understands how to use both components to perform accurate chronological comparisons of the point in time represented by Timestamp.  It works exactly the way you would expect it to work.  There is no magic.  A Timestamp that represens a point in time that's later than another Timestamp sorts after the second Timestamp.  The fact that the client side representation uses two numbers is immaterial to its observed ordering behavior.

Comment: I know Timestamp is supposed to be as granular as nanoseconds based on the document. However, when I retrieve the actual data and log it, it's always  in the form of `Timestamp { _seconds: 1543528094, _nanoseconds: 446000000 }` where last 6 digits are always zero for nanosecods.  I am not sure if it's Firestore's client rounding up the 6 digits or the server generates Timestamp in microseconds.